# IPhones- Have the keyboard slide out with the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard

We have a view open with keyboard shown ， but when the back button clicked , the view slide out from right while the keyboard will slide only when the view disappeared. 
if we call resignFirstResponder at viewwilldisappear, the view slide to the right while keyboard slide down at same time.
Is it possible to  let the keyboard slide out with the view?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to do what you want, but...
Basically, keyboard is just a view, presented in it's own UIWindow on top of all your other windows.
So, theoretically, what you need to do is to find keyboard view and move it in desired direction. I think you should use `transform` property and don't mess up with `frame`.

```
Class keyboardClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIPeripheralHostView");
for ( UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] ) {
    for ( UIView *subview in window.subviews ) {
        if ( [subview isKindOfClass:keyboardClass] ) {
            // that's keyboard
        }
    }
}
```

Edited:
If you're talking about UINavigationController and it's default slide animations during push / pop, then, you just need to invoke `resignFirstResponder` in `viewDidDisappear` and `becomeFirstResponder` in `viewWillAppear` on your text view. That way your keyboard will slide along with your view.

Comment: It works but it still have other question. The keyboard is  not slide right but the right-down corner. And when i enter the view second time ,the keyboard can slide in.

Comment: Keyboard slides down as a part of standard keyboard dismiss process. I think you invoke resignFirstResponder in your viewWillDissapear method. Maybe you should observe keyboard notifications and then cancel it's original animations `[view.layer removeAllAnimations]` and perform your own animations.

Comment: removeallanimations can't prevent the keyboard slide down , it seemed the system perform the calculate of the keyboard animation after keyboarddidhidden.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this and it works in iOS 5.1, however, I don't think this is recommended behaviour.

```
    for (UIWindow *keyboardWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    if ([[keyboardWindow description] hasPrefix:@"<UITextEffectsWindow"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [keyboardWindow description]);
        [UIWindow beginAnimations:@"fadeKeyboard" context:nil];
        keyboardWindow.frame = CGRectMake(keyboardWindow.frame.origin.x + keyboardWindow.frame.size.width, keyboardWindow.frame.origin.y, keyboardWindow.frame.size.width, keyboardWindow.frame.size.height);
        [UIWindow commitAnimations];
    }
```

You can also use a notification UIKeyboardWillHideNotification to detect when the keyboard is going to hide, or just use the above code manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try sticking `resignFirstresponder` in the `viewDidDisappear` method instead.

Comment: call resignfirstresponder here , the view slide out and keyboard slide out when the view disappeared , same with never call resignfirstresponder  or call it ad didunload.

Answer (score 0):

```
          **Set notificatins and use these methods.....Hope it solve problem:

           First of all set your whole view in scrollView**
          -(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notif
     {
          NSTimeInterval duration = 0.4;
             [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:
                ^{
              scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,scrollOriginalFrame.size.height);
               }];
              keyboardVisible=NO;
     }
     -(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notif
     {

         scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, scrollOriginalFrame.size.height+235);
         NSTimeInterval duration = 0.4;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:
          ^{
             [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,162) animated:YES];

        }];
           keyboardVisible=YES;
           }
               **In viewDidLoad() add this**

        //keyboard
        scrollOriginalFrame=self.view.frame;
          scrollOriginalFrame.size.height-=103;
         scrollView.contentSize=scrollOriginalFrame.size;
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                   selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
               [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
keyboardVisible=NO;
```

Comment: It seem that we din't have a scrollview. And it seem not work also , the keyboardDidHide is called when the keyboard begin to slide, at that moment the view have already disappeared.